# Linux - Check if string is in list

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script and I want to check if a string is in a list. 
Like: string = "Hello World!", List=("foo", "bar").
Python example:

```
if name in list: # Another way -> if name in ["foo", "bar"]
  # work to do
else:
  sys.exit(1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: we need to see samples of "a string" and "a list". Please edit your Q to include the **small** sampe data set and the required output from that input.  Good luck.

Comment: Added samples for string and list.

Comment: You could (mis)use an associative array for holding the list, where each list element is a key. While defining the list looks a bit ugly, because you must define a dummy value for each key-value-pair in the list, it makes searching easy. See for example [here](http://superuser.com/questions/195598/test-if-element-is-in-array-in-bash).

Answer (score 10):

There are a number of ways, the simplest I see is:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

WORD_LIST="one two three"
MATCH="twox"

if echo "$WORD_LIST" | grep -qw "$MATCH"; then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This has multiple bugs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: Much simpler to just do `case $WORD_LIST in *"$MATCH"*) ... ;; esac`

Comment: This 'case' statement matches for sub-words as well.

Comment: This may fail if, for example, $MATCH="--help".